# PHP operating on a variable upon setting it in PHP

Tags: php, class

This might look as a stupid question. But, I have a class with some `public` string variables defined in it.

Upon assigning a value to a property:

```
$a = new user();
$a->FirstName = "sth";
```

I want to store the value as UTF8.

I know I can do this via:

```
$a->Firstname = utf8_encode("sth");
```

However, I want the object to do this automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting this straight, but you're hardcoding this string, right? Then just saving your .php file in UTF8 would suffice.

Comment: Are you sure you know what `utf8_encode` does? It very specifically converts ISO-8859-1 strings to UTF-8. How can you guarantee that all strings you want to store in this object will be ISO-8859-1 encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Otherwise no, the object cannot do it automatically.

Not automatically, but [automagically](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)!

```
<?php

class User {
    /**
     * Change the public to private/protected!
     */
    private $Firstname;

    /**
     * This is automatically called upon calling a value that can't be written "from the outside".
     */
    public function __set( $key, $value ) {
        $this->$key = utf8_encode( $value );
    }

    public function __get( $key ) {
        return isset( $this->$key ) ? $this->$key : false;
    }
}

$user = new User;
$user->Firstname = 'Berry';

echo $user->Firstname;
```

The better solution would be to refactor in using mutators and accessors, or better yet, learn OO.

Comment: by the way, can u elaborate how can I use this? it's like I say: `$a->FirstName = "sth"; ` ??

Comment: @Eskach While this will work short-term, you might want to consider refactoring to a more encapsulated version. This will save your behind in the long run.

Comment: @Eskach Updated this with a small usage example. It works by changing the public class members to private, and __set( ) will be called upon calling $user->Firstname.

Comment: And, would u please tell me what will happen when a function inside the class tries to assign a value to the property? Is the __set also called?

Comment: @Eskach No, __set will only be called if the variable is private *and* unwriteable. Private variables are writeable from within the class itself, meaning it would be written to directly, as opposed to being proxied through __set.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use *setters* and *getters*. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Like:

```
class User
{
  protected $Firstname;

  public function setFirstname($Firstname) {
    $this->Firstname = utf8_encode($Firstname);
  }

  public function getFirstname() {
    return $this->Firstname;
  }
}
```

Example using magic methods:

```
class User
{
  protected $data = array(
    'Firstname' => '',
    // ...
  );

  public function __set($key, $value) {
    if (isset($this->data[$key])) {
        $this->data[$key] = utf8_encode($value);
    }
  }

  public function __get($key) {
    return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
  }
}
```

Edit: I'm using `$data` so that there is at least a minimum of control of what properties can be set.

Comment: so, this is not possible to do with __set() ?? I read everywhere that these are for **undefined** variables only.

Comment: @Eskach: `__set` is fine too. Probably preferable actually (though I'm not familiar with it). The point here is to use accessors and mutators, however you go about doing that.

Comment: @Eskach See the 2nd example. Hope it helps. Also I really don't like this approach. Neither public properties nor magic methods for getting and setting properties. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd designed your class to have accessors and mutators, rather than public access to raw variables, then this would be easy.

Original code:

```
class user {
   private $FirstName = '';

   public function getFirstName() {
      return $this->FirstName;
   }
}
```

Solution code:

```
class user {
   private $FirstName = '';

   public function getFirstName() {
      return utf8_encode($this->FirstName);
   }
}
```

I suggest moving towards this approach.

Otherwise no, the object cannot do it automatically.

---

**Edit**

`__set` and `__get` might be the most appropriate way to implement this. I'm not too familiar with them, and it doesn't really matter: the point I'm making here is to use accessors and mutators... however you end up implementing them.